# How to handle Wireworld duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've just closed [Shortest Wireworld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52570/194) as a duplicate of [Simulate the Wireworld cellular automaton](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9292/194). However, this is one of those lose-lose situations:

- Leave the new question open: answers to two essentially identical questions are split between them, or answers to the older one are reposted.
- Close the new question: no-one can post answers to either, because the previous question was already closed.

I think that the best solution is to edit the older question and reopen it. Does anyone object to me removing the last paragraph:

> I will pick the winner as a combination of shortest code, usability, speed, and prettiness. I don't really care too much about prettiness, but usability is pretty important. Just make sure that you keep the code short. Good luck!

and then voting to reopen?

Comment: Check out my [recent edit](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/simulate-the-wireworld-cellular-automaton).  I think it can be reopened now.

Answer (score 4):

Since all the existing answers are already golfing their code, I think it's fine to turn this into a regular code golf. However, PhiNotPi is still active, so maybe he just wants to fix it himself.

There is also a third option (which I'd consider if the original author is no longer active, and the specs match up exactly): merging the old question into the new, which would move all answers over and replace the old question with a note linking to the new.

Comment: If merging, would it open up the use of languages created after the fist question, but before the second?